# Directadmin combine / merge spf records

Tags: dns, spf, nameservers, directadmin

We have these two TXT records running in our Directadmin DNS for the same domain name.

```
v=spf1 +a +mx -all
v=spf1 +a +mx2 -all
```

I am asked to merge them to have a single TXT record for both mx and mx2.

With everything I've tried so far, the system says 'invalid name'.

Does anyone know how to do this for Directadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal `mx2` is not a valid value to include in SPF, but if you mean that you want to include an additional mail server, you don't need to do it since the existing `mx` value will match any mx record for the current domain - i.e. that all mail exchangers for the domain are also allowed to send.

Also, the `+` chars you have are not necessary - `+` is the default action.

Overall, I expect your merged result would simply be:

```
v=spf1 a mx -all
```

Please comment if that's not what you meant, and clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro. This explains exactly what I found confusing when reading into it on how to do this. They should write like this in official documentation! Thanks again!